# Configurable Product options box not showing on the front end

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, attributes, configurable-product, frontend, custom-options

The drop down selection box is not showing for configurable products, the configurable product itself is showing but not the options to choose which simple product is selected.

It is probably notable that I am using the latest version of the organic internet SCP (Simple Configurable Products) Module.

I have made sure of the following:

1. Both the simple and configurable products are enabled.
2. Both the simple and configurable products are in stock.
3. The Simple Products have 1 quantity in stock.
4. The Configurable product has associated simple products.
5. Configurable Attribute is set for all product types.
6. Configurable Attribute is in the correct Attribute Set.
7. Configurable Attribute has options.
8. Configurable product is visible in catalogue and Search.

My Problem is the same as this thread.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/38811/

Please Help me avoid further hair loss.

Thanks

[image: Product Options Not Showing]

Comment: Did you rebuild your indexes?

Answer (score 6):

Was the product created programmatically or via import script?

If the configurable product doesn't have a value specified for the `options_cointainer` attribute, the effect will be similar to the one described by you.

You can solve the problem by saving the configurable product from Admin Panel, selecting a value for the the "Display Product Options in" of the "Design" tab of the product details.

Otherwise the following will do that programmatically:

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load()->setOptionsContainer('container1')->save();
```

or

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load()->setOptionsContainer('container2')->save();
```

Regards

Comment: THANK YOU so much. I had already tracked down the problem to being the  "options_container" which was referenced in the catalog.xml file. What I hadn't figured out was that each individual product had to be set, not just your overall store setting (seems totally stupid that it doesn't fallback.)

Comment: Have been searching for a solution to this FOREVER. I knew it had something to do with the container, but even though I was setting it in my import script it still wasn't being saved correctly, this totally fixed it, thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve my similar issues by reindexing my data. However, my reindexing processes were locked up so I had to follow the instructions at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14127430/magento-indexes-issue-cant-reindex before the issue was finally resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve spent hours trying to figure out the problem of why my product was not showing the “Product options/attributes” on the public site.

After ensuring all the setup for the attributes, the set, the stock availability, product visibility, categories being selected, etc were CORRECT, and After lots of research, I found the following answer on this thread: 
http://www.scorgit.com/blog/magento-associated-products-not-showing-up/

After ensuring that everything was set up properly (as shortly explained above and lots of online threads), all I had to do was simply to open the main “configurable product” (parent) in edit mode, go to the “attributes” tab, and press “Reset filter”, then “Select all”, which puts checkmarks on all the product options and then hit SAVE. By selecting them all, this column not only selects them but in fact makes these product options AVAILABLE (enabled) for the product!

To bad the column is just called nothing and only shows a “checkmark”. This left-most column should be called “enable?” or something to make it clear that if it’s checked, it’s not just for selecting it, but for enabling it and making it live on the website (so that product options do appear).

See attached image to see where I had to “check” all of my child products (within the configurable product) were set.

Hope this helps

Jaime
[image]

Comment: Your URL gives 404 please update

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem when importing products into two stores, after the import none of the configurable options were available until I went to the products switched to each store and saved the newly imported products. I fixed this problem by adding some custom code to the end of the importer after it had created the products to save it in each store

```
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $productId = $product->getIdBySku($importData['sku']);
    $product->load($productId);
    if ($product && $product->getId()) {
        $product->setStoreId(1);
        $product->save();
        $product->setStoreId(2);
        $product->save();
    }
```

This will slow down the import slightly but it will result in products that are fully available straight from the import.

(I am using a custom Advanced Dataflow profile to import the products but this can be added to any import set up)