# Magento 1.9 : Configurable Options not showing on product page Issue

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, product-attribute

I have a site on Magento 1.9,the product options do not show on the front end for configurable products. It throws the error like this.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasClassName' of null

Currently I have not made no changes on the site but I am unable to figure out the exact problem. How do I go ahead. 
I have refered to previous answers([link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8143/configurable-product-options-box-not-showing-on-the-front-end?rq=1)) which mentioned about checking following things in case for product options not shown up on product page. And in my case these all conditions are met and yet I'm stuck on this.

1. visibilty = not show inidividually
2. stock = in stock
3. attribute set = the same as configurable product
4. price = also set
5. status = enable

   [image]

Comment: Js confliction, can you disable the swatch and check

Comment: How do i disable the swatch?

Comment: open the backend, inside  System -> Config section,you will find the swatch tab, disable that and check

Comment: is it worked now ?

Comment: @RahulSingh It worked.Thank you .I was checking what should i do for color swatch related attributes ?

Comment: One query, do we need to add only color-related attributes to swatches, maybe size attribute was also present in configuration by me.

Comment: I have added the answer, also added how to add the swatches product follow the tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case swatches-product.js is Conflicting with prototype.js

Open the Backend, inside **System -> Configuration** Section, you will find the Configurable Swatches tab, disable that and check.

[image: swatch]

To add swatches product,  [check here](https://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-configurable-swatch.html)